# how to load a php page in html and also a button for pop-up

Tags: php, jquery, html

Describing as example: assume A= www.domain.com/test.html is a page and B = www.domain/php/forum/ is another php running forum .

it is possible to load B on A in somehow ? and also how may I add php forums as a button popup ? php page is on another folder not in the same folder.

please any advise. Thanks

Comment: To the question "Is it possible", the answer is YES. If the underlying question was "how to do it", I would suggest to code it and come back here with faulty code if you get stuck. Alternatively, hire someone who can do it if you can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you want to do is to use an `iframe` to embed one document into another.  For the most basic implementation your HTML on `www.domain.com/test.html` would look like

```
<iframe src="www.domain/php/forum/"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframe in a HTML way, or get the page by cURL or file_get_contents in a php way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you changed test.html to test.php you could include the index of you forum.

```
<?php include 'php/forum/index.php'; ?>
```

I don't see why you would want to include it all however? Perhaps make a widget that shows some useful information that you want on your homepage and include that?